# how can i solve cross domain problem in python flask server response to js?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jsonp, cross-origin-read-blocking

I've tried the Flask server response with JavaScript.

but in front end has occurred error as follows.

> datatables.js:10449 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response...

So I tried to solve this problem using CORS.

Here is my try in python test code.

```
from flask import request, Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = ('Content-Type', 'application/json')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin(origins = '*')

def get():
    try:
        parameter1 = request.args.get('parameter1')
        parameter2 = request.args.get('parameter2')
        parameter3 = request.args.get('parameter3')
        parameter4 = request.args.get('parameter4')
        parameter5 = request.args.get('parameter5')
    para_dict = {'parameter1':parameter1,
         'parameter2':parameter2,
         'parameter3':parameter3,
         'parameter4':parameter4,
         'parameter5':parameter5,
         }
    return jsonify(para_dict)
```

In JavaScript, jsonp is used to eliminate response errors, as shown in the code below.

```
var url = 'localhost:5002/';
var param = {
    parameter1: $ {
        param.parameter1
    },
    parameter2: $ {
        param.parameter2
    },
    parameter3: $parameter3.val().trim(),
    parameter4: $parameter4.val().trim(),
    parameter5: $parameter5.val().trim()
};
$.get(url, param, function(data) {
    if (data.status) {
        if (!$parameter3.val().trim()) $parameter3.val(data.value);
        else if (!$parameter4.val().trim()) $parameter3.val(data.value);
        else if (!$parameter5.val().trim()) $parameter3.val(data.value);

        chart.addPointAnnotation({
            x: data.x,
            y: data.y,
            label: {
                text: 'operation_point',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '1rem',
                    padding: {
                        left: 10,
                        right: 10,
                        top: 5,
                        bottom: 5,
                    }
                }
            },
        });
    } else {
        alert(data.msg);
    }
}, 'jsonp');//using jsonp
```

And when I checked the network, I think it transmitted well.

Below is the network header information.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 98
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2020 00:31:50 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.7.3
```

But still get the same error.

What more should I set up than cors and jsonp?

Comment: does your browser perform an OPTIONS CORS pre-flight request? if so, does your server handle it correctly?

Comment: oh, wait ... you're using JSONP ... there should be no CORS issues with JSONP, i.e. you wouldn't even need the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header at all with JSONP - does your server **send** JSONP? it shouldn't send an application/json header if you're using JSONP

Comment: Does that mean I don't have to use CORS in python if i use JSONP?

Comment: correct, you only have to respond with valid JSONP - which isn't the same as JSON by the way - and with content-type `application/javascript`

Comment: If so, which one is the better way to cut CORD on a Python server or change JSONP to JSON?

Comment: whatever works for you - I have no opinion on what you want to do with your code